# Need To Remove Previous Marker From Map Without refreshing the google map

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need to remove the previously added marker ,without refreshing the screen ,tried many codes for past 2 days but not able to do. This question might sound like a duplicate ,yes it is but in my case I am not able to fix the bug ,any suggestions and helps would be very useful. I have attached my code below.Thanks In advance.
P.S : I am new to google maps (project built on C# code,javascript, asp.net mvc, ms sql db)

```
 var map = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        lat: 11.0168,
        lng: 76.9558
    });
    geolocate();
    function geolocate() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("loadmap", "LiveTracking")',
            type: "Get",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (results) {
                debugger;
                var result = JSON.parse(results);

                    var lat = parseFloat(result[0].Latitude)
                    var lng = parseFloat(result[0].Longitude)
                    var VehicleId = result[0].VehicleID;
                    var Speed = result[0].Speed;
                    var abc = ("Vehicle:" + VehicleId + " , " + "Speed:" + Speed )
                    map.addMarker({
                        lat: lat,
                        lng: lng,
                        icon: {
                            url: '/Content/Images/zaz.png',
                            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(65, 65),
                        },
                        title: 'vehicle',
                        infoWindow: {
                            content: abc
                        },
                    });
               // }
            }
        })
    }


Most commonly suggested method was to add an marker[] and push in it and call the delete function ,which I tried but can't able to achieve it.
```

Hope anyone can help me out,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this documentation?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

It has clearMarkers() before setting the empty array.

```
function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    markers = [];
  }

function clearMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(null);
  }

function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }
```

Comment: yes I went through this ,but my problem is I get stuck where to implement the code and ,in my code I have used map.addMarker() function ,could you please help me out to where to plca this code correctly in my code

Comment: So for your marker I would try map.marker.setMap(null);

Comment: You could create a new function inside map called deleteMarker() and inside that have marker.setMap(null); The function would be called wherever the action to remove the marker is triggered eg on a button.

Comment: thank you for your response, but I tried this code marker.setMap(null);  ,in chrome browser(f12) console error saying that marker.setMap(null) is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="googleMap()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 300px; width: 300px"></div>
    <a onclick="removeMarker()">Remove marker</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">

          var map, myLatLng, marker;

          function googleMap() {
            var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.645813,-0.382000),
              zoom: 15,
              scrollwheel: false,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.645945,-0.382837);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatLng, map: map });
         };

         function removeMarker() {
            marker.setMap(null);
         };

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried the above code and it hid the marker (I removed the maps api key though).

Comment: tried your code ,it removes the marker ,but google map is flickering(refreshing), my motto is to show the vehicle oving in the map without flickering,in marker i have set vehicle icon

Comment: I can't see it flickering and not sure how to fix that - maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157001/update-reload-markers-without-reloading-google-map